# Human Body and RNA/DNA

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

After research I found that enzymes are responsible for metabolism, specifically catabolism and anabolism. This in turn creates the necessary chemicals in your body. The only question left is: what are enzymes? I asked in Biology and the answer led me to enzymes being created by ribosomes. Ribosomes by RNA. RNA by the four chemicals, adenine, guanine, cytosine, and uracil. *Okay* so, my question is: what chemical elements are those four chemicals comprised of?

Comment: That is very broad, could you narrow it down please or break it up into multiple questions. Or try asking at biology.se first and then come back here for the chemistry bits...

Comment: If this is still confusing/broad please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @Sciiiiience It is indeed too broad, an answer could cover an entire book.  See something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolism to get started and try to narrow it down, please.  It's a fascinating area, but it's going to require some more specific inquiries.

Comment: @jonsca Okay thank you. Feel free to close this question or whatever it is happens.

Comment: @Sciiiiience It's a great topic area, so I'm looking forward to your edits, then it can certainly be reopened thereafter.

Comment: There are hundreds of enzymes; each one was created to do a specific task (some have a lot of leeway, others are quite narrow). Most proteins are encoded in the DNA. mRNA is created from the DNA (by an enzyme) and moves to the ribosomes where the encoded enzymes are made. [Here][1] is a chart of metabolic pathways in cells.    [1]: http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/m3782?lang=en&region=US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search would tell you what the 4 nucleobases for RNA are made of:

**Uracil:** 4 Carbon 4 Hydrogen 2 Nitrogen 2 Oxygen

[image: u]

**Adenine:** 5 Carbon 5 Hydrogen 5 Nitrogen

[image: a]

**Guanine:** 5 Carbon 5 Hydrogen 5 Nitrogen 1 Oxygen

[image: g]

**Cytosine:** 4 Carbon 5 Hydrogen 3 Nitrogen 1 Oxygen

[image: c]